# Access x property on svg element in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement a transform wherein an element moves a couple of pixels to the left  by several pixels when a user mouses over it.  How can I access the x property of a bar so I can pass in a relative position?

Here's my code; it's pretty standard except that I don't have an axis on the bar chart.

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)


var tip = d3.tip() 
    .attr('class','d3-tip') 
    .html(function(d, i) {
      return "<span style='color:red'>" + d.Word +"</span>";
  });


svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(words)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i*(w/dataset.length);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d){
    return (h-(800) 
      );
  })
  .attr("width", 40)
  .attr("class", "rectangle")
  .attr("id", function(d, i){return "rect"+i})
  .attr("height", function(d, i){
    // var barheight = d.Dispersion*100
    return "200px" 
  })
  .on("mouseover", tip.show)
  .on("mouseout", tip.hide);
svg.call(tip);

$('.rectangle').mouseover(function () {
  var rect = d3.select("#"+this.id)
  rect.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .attr("width", 58)
      .duration(500)
      .attr("height", 220+"px")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {return d.color}); 
      .attr("x", 50) //this goes to a particular position in the parent node 
  });
```

Comment: not `d3.select(element).attr('x')` ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the attribute dx? Just set it to -5 on mouseover and 0 on mouseout

Comment: I got it.  The attr('x') wound up working.  Classic problem of staring at something for too long and needing a break. Thanks!